# My code cant redirect by passport js . Authentication issue

Tags: node.js, passport.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to authenticate using passport js and if authentication is successful then redirect to homepage but it cant redirect

I have tried to check if passport.authentication calls function or not.But yes it can handle what to do if authentication fail but cant handle what to do if it's true.

first signin form submits and form action="/users/create-session"
.
.
.

//this is action controller page...

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const passport=require('passport');




router.post('/create-session',passport.authenticate(
    'local',
    {failureRedirect:'/users/signin'},
),usersController.createSession);
```

.
.
.
//passport local page....

```
const passport=require('passport');
const LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User=require('../models/user');
```

//authentiacate using passport

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField:'email'
    },
    function(email,password,done){
        //find a user and establish the identity
        User.findOne({email:email},function(err,user){
              if(err){
                console.log('Error in finding user --> Passport');
                return done(err);
            }
            if(!user||user.password!=password){
                console.log('Invalid Username/Password');
                return done(null,false);
            }
              return(null,user);
             })
    }
));
```

//serializing the user to decide which key is to be kept in cookies

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user.id);
})
```

//deserializing the user from the key in tha cookies

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    User.findById(id,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error in finding User --> Passport');
            return done(err);
        }
        return done(null,user);
    });
})

module.exports=passport;
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
//usersController.createSession page
.
.

```
module.exports.createSession=function(req,res){

    return res.redirect('/');

}
```

It was expected that after signin if password is correct it should redirect to 'locolhost:8000/'  but wheel keeps on and after sometimes it says page is not working local host didn't send any data`enter code here

Answer (score 0):

in code
//authenticate using passport

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
usernameField:'email'
},
function(email,password,done){
    //find a user and establish the identity
    User.findOne({email:email},function(err,user){
          if(err){
            console.log('Error in finding user --> Passport');
            return done(err);
        }
        if(!user||user.password!=password){
            console.log('Invalid Username/Password');
            return done(null,false);
        }
          return(null,user);
.
.

-----------------------------------------------
//instead return(null,user); .... return done(null,user);  must be there
.
.
.

         })
}
));
```